# jQuery - Array of image URL's prints incorrectly

Tags: jquery, image, append

I have an array of image URL's and I wish to load these, in order to get the proper dimensions and then do stuff with them / output as needed.

Here's my code for handling that (loops an array of image URL's):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.IMAGES.length; i++) {

    var img = $("<img />").attr('src', data.IMAGES[i].url)
    .load(function() {

        if (!this.complete || typeof this.naturalWidth == "undefined" || this.naturalWidth == 0) {

            console.log("Error");

        } else {

            // This does output, but not correctly...

            if ( this.width > 299 ) {
                cache.$shareImages.append('<div class="share-image">' + img + '</div>');
            }

        }

    });
}
```

jQuery seems to append the content, but does so in a way which is odd. Here's an example of the output generated:

```
<div class="share-image">[object Object]</div>
```

I want to output the img tag itself that was created dynamically.

Why is this happening and how to solve it?

Thanks,
Mikey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a string concatenation with:

```
 '<div class="share-image">' + img + '</div>'
```

...so it basically does a `toString()` on `img`, producing `[object Object]`.

Perhaps you could try:

```
$('<div class="share-image"></div>').append(this).appendTo(cache.$shareImages);
```

EDIT: Note that the `.load()` handlers will run asynchronously after the loop has finished, at which point the `img` variable will be set to whatever img element was created last in the loop. So within the load use `this` to refer to the particular img just loaded.

Comment: Weirdly, this seems to output an image, but only the last in the array. Is it overwriting itself somehow?

Comment: See my update. You've hit upon a common problem with event handlers assigned in a loop.

Comment: Excellent! Your edit made this work. Referencing 'this' did the trick (and your method of using append() of course). Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I wasn't paying enough attention to pick up the second problem until you mentioned it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to chain the [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), append the image to the newly created div , and then append that to your target

```
$('<div class="share-image"></div>').append(this).appendTo(cache.$shareImages);
```

---

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/blowsie/UCx73/

Comment: That's not quite right: the OP is trying to make the img a child of the div, but your code appends the img as a sibling of the div.